# Materialize dropdown in modal dialog: I can't set the value displayed dynamically

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, materialize

I have a Materialize dropdown in a modal dialog. When I open the modal I want to dynamically set the selected item before the modal is displayed and to display the item in the dropdown text. Here's the code. (note I do also have data-icon set but removed from the code to make it easier to read).

```
  <div id="modalRiskCalculator" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s1">
          <label>BVR reach (daily)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="risk-div">
          <div id="jacTest" class="input-field col s4">
            <select id="riskBVRvalue" class="risk-select">
              <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option> 
              <option value="5">10M+</option>
              <option value="4">1M+</option>
              <option value="3">100K+</option>
              <option value="2">10K+</option>
              <option value="1">1K+</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


$('#riskBVRvalue').val(3);
$('#modalRiskCalculator').modal('open');
```

The modal opens fine and when I click on the dropdown it shows the val(3) item selected, but it only updates the dropdown text when I click off the dropdown. What I need is for the dropdown text to update when the modal is opened.

Comment: This does appear to be an issue with modals; I tried the above code on my main page and it worked OK (dynamically setting the value in the $(document).ready). So maybe it's to do with the modal not initializing properly?

Answer (score 0):

Scrub that - it's nothing to do with modals; the effect happens on the main page.

It works when you dynamically set it from $(document).ready). But it doesn't when I try to set it from another trigger (e.g. button click), which is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
You simply need to reinitialize the select element after the dynamic changes, i.e.
$('select').formSelect();